# how to fix this Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') from axios in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

## im try to use axios in node.js with common.js

> encludes with **error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')**

- Axios 1.1.3
- Node.js 16.15.0

```
const axios = require("axios").default;

async function test(){
    const data =await axios.get("https://www.google.com")
    return data
}

test().then((res) => console.log(res.data))
```

## im try this

```
const axios = require("axios").default;

async function test(){
    const data =await axios.get("https://www.google.com")
    return data
}

test().then((res) => console.log(res.data)) // response => Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

Comment: What version of axios do you use?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5011

Comment: im use 1.1.3 version

Answer (score 1):

```
const axios = require('axios')
```

This will fix the problem

Comment: yes but in vscode dont show me suggestions this is not bad but if im use default i can see all suggestions from axios (get, post, create ...)